# capture output of a running process in Java

Tags: java, process, stdout

(I'm using Windows 7) I know how to start a process, pass some arguments and read the output of that process.

```
import java.io.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  {
        ProcessBuilder pb
                = new ProcessBuilder("java", "ProgramFoo", "ArgBar");
        Process process = pb.start();
        final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader
                    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
    }
}
```

But what I want to do, is to read the output of a **running** process. Maybe by its PID or name.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. At least in a platform independent way.

Comment: @aioobe I forgot to mention the reason of telling the OS that I'm using. I wouldn't mind if it's a just for Windows solution.

Comment: @M1990 can you please explain what you're trying to do more? If a process is already running there's either no stdout allocated (e.g. chrome.exe) or it is already linked to a command line window and the stream is being read by `cmd`. In case you started the new process earlier from the same Java process, just hold on the `Process` object, pass it along, and read the stream later on.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I have several hardcoded-no source available-legacy programs. They output several lines of text (to the console) each minute (they can last hours running). I need to execute these programs, and send their output to a server.

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/ for better handling of processes.

Alternatively, you could get an InputStream from the process you already have and read it like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

stdout = br.readLine();
while (stdout != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(stdout);
    stdout = br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Hmm... not sure if you understood the question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to launch a process external from your current application and both pass input and retrieve its output. The Apache Commons Exec library will allow you to do both of those things. Is there something I missed?

Comment: OP is *not* trying to launch a process: *"But what I want to do, is to read the output of a **running** process."*